# Animation not working in CSS

Tags: css, css-animations

I am using Codepen and would like one of my elements to fade in and out. I can't find any errors in my code but it is still not working. Thanks for any help!

The item is a little logo box that you press to open up a new window with text. It currently changes on mouseover but I would also like to make it fade in and out so that people know they need to click it.

Thanks Danko, I got it working now! Can't believe the issue was that simple haha :)

```
.mainlink a:link, a:visited {
    display: block;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/E3EQRWV.jpg?2);
    background-size:cover; 
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;  
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 2px solid black;
    animation: fadin 3s infinite alternate;
    -webkit-animation: fadin 3s infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: fadin 3s infinite alternate;
    -o-animation: fadin 3s infinite alternate;}

@keyframes fadin {
  0% {opacity: 100%;}
  50% {opacity: 50%;}
  100% {opacity: 0%;}}

@-webkit-keyframes fadin{ 
  0% {opacity: 100%;}
  50% {opacity: 50%;}
  100% {opacity: 0%;}}

@-moz-keyframes fadin{ 
  0% {opacity: 100%;}
  50% {opacity: 50%;}
  100% {opacity: 0%;}}

@-o-keyframes fadin{ 
  0% {opacity: 100%;}
  50% {opacity: 50%;}
  100% {opacity: 0%;}}
```

Comment: which browsers does the problem occur in? Can you create a jsfiddle demonstrating the issue?

Comment: If The answer was usefull don't forget to mark it as the correct **check icon next to the answer**

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is `opacity` doesn't accept `%` as unit value. Change it to a value between

> `1` and `0` Where 1 = 100% and 0 = 0%

Try this:

```
@keyframes fadin {
  0% {opacity: 1;}
  100% {opacity: 0;}
}
```

```css
.mainlink a {
  display: block;
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/E3EQRWV.jpg?2);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 2px solid black;
  animation: fadin 3s infinite alternate;
  -webkit-animation: fadin 3s infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: fadin 3s infinite alternate;
  -o-animation: fadin 3s infinite alternate;
}
@keyframes fadin {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadin {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadin {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes fadin {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mainlink">
  <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```